# Python appengine Query does not work when using a variable

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to use a fetcher method to retrieve items from my datastore.  If I use the following

```
def getItem(item_id):
    q = Item.all()
    q.filter("itemid = ", item_id)
```

It fails because nothing is returned.  If I hard code in an item like

```
def getItem(item_id):
    q = Item.all()
    q.filter("itemid = ", 9000)
```

it fetches just fine, and sings merrily along.  I have tried every which way to get this to work.  I have used

```
result = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Item WHERE item_id = :1 LIMIT 1",
    title).fetch(1)
```

to the same effect.  If I hard code in a number, works fine.  I have tried setting the select statement as a local string, assembling it that way, casting the int as a string, and nothing.  When I output the SELECT statement to the screen, looks fine.  I can cut ans paste the output into the string, and whammo, it works.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it make any difference if you do this:

```
def getItem(item_id):
    q = Item.all()
    q.filter("itemid = ", int(item_id))
```

The most likely cause of the problem that I can see is that the item_id parameter may be a string even though it is holding a numerical value. Coerce it to an int, and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I could kiss you.  Of course it is an int, I kept thinking in terms of building a sql string.  Works great.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Good news, Lloyd. Glad to hear it.